# Do animated Gif files have GIFGIF embedded in them?

Tags: php, animated-gif

I am currently re-writing an existing tool in PHP that another person started for optimizing images, for `gif` images,I will convert to `png` and then optimize the `png file`.  For `animated gifs` I will run through the program called `Gifsicle` which can optimize animated `gif` images.

In some of the existing codebase, the other guy identified animated gif images with the file extension `gifgif` as you can see in the snippets below, they contain all the code that references this `gifgif`.

I have search Google and I cannot find a mention of a `gifgif` file anywhere, in addition I have never in my life heard of one.

Can someone help me figure out does the actual extension `gifgif` exist?  Is it possibly something that is embedded in `animated gif` files?

The code...

```
$types = array("gif", "png", "gifgif", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp");
```

and

```
if (substr($type, 0, 6) === "gifgif") 
{
    $type = "gifgif";
}
```

and

```
case "gifgif":
    $dest_file .= ".gif";
    $cmd = "/usr/bin/gifsicle -O2 $src_file > $dest_file";
    exec($cmd, $return, $error);
```

Comment: Sounds like that person was making up stuff, just so that xe would distinguish non-animated and animated GIFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a standard extension and the code you show appears to care only about file extensions.

Presumably the developer of the system you are using came up with the convention and it is unique to that system.

Comment: You are correct, I just confirmed imagemagick returns `GIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIF` as the file extension on an animated gif and just `gif` on a regular gif image

Comment: Actually with more test I now see that ImageMagick returns `GIF x Number of frames` so my image had 7 frames so it shoed `GIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIF` and the code checks to make sure there is at least 2 `GIFGIF` and saves anything with 2 or more as `GIFGIF`

Answer (score 1):

`gifgif` is not a valid extension - and by all means is not a valid way to check whether the file is an animated gif file.  In order to check whether the file is an animated gif, you need to actually parse the content of the file and check for frame headers.  This function will do it simply:

```
<?php
function is_ani($filename) {
    return (bool)preg_match('#(\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00\x2C.*){2,}#s', file_get_contents($filename));
}
?>
```

P.S. This is not my function, but borrowed from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php  There is another version given in the same post.  That version of the function reads the file in chunks and checks each individual chunk, however this approach will not correctly, because the header may end up being split between two chunks.

Comment: I just manually ran the Imagemagick which is the program that gets the extension.  on a Gif image it returns Gif on an animated gif it returns `GIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIF` so I can see he is saving the output and if it is `GIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIF` he is grabbing `gifgif` out of it

Comment: So it is actually being checked with imagemagick, he is just saving `gifgif` for animated images after it has been checked and confirmed to be an animated gif

Comment: Ok, that may make sense.  He's not using the file extension, but the file type returned by imagemagic

Comment: yeah I couldnt figure out what was going on until I manually ran imagemagick on an actual animated gif and saw the resulkt is not `gif` but `GIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIFGIF` or who know's maybe it is `GIFx Number of frames` and he checks to makes sure there are at least 2 frames with `GIFGIF`